# Overwrite CSS in ms-dropdown plugin

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

`ms-dropdown` plugin bootstrap is applying only the predefined css that is written in the plugin, how to overwrite it?

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    try {
        alert('Enter');
        $("#<%=ddlBrand.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
});
```

#### Dropdown control

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBrand" runat="server" Width="515px" TabIndex="6" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBrand_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

#### The plugin to be added

```
<link href="../Styles/Vehicle/dd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<script src="../Scripts/Vehicle/jquery.dd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

enter code here
```

C# code

```
protected void ddlBrand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    Bindtitle();
}

private void Bindtitle()
{
    if (ddlBrand != null)
    {
        foreach (ListItem li in ddlBrand.Items)
        {
            li.Attributes["title"] = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Images/Vehicles/BrandLogo/" + li.Text + ".png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing pretty much your entire question content here. Recommend you re-read it and edit it with the corrections

Comment: hi jwpfox,thanks for you reply..the problem is binding the data and the images int he dropdown with responsive ..here i had used the jquery plugin named msdropdown...but the issue is the bootstrap is not applying ..please tell if any method exist..,thank you